# Getting bounds from Riemann sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

$y=\sum_{i=0}^9\frac{1}{10\sqrt 3} \frac{1}{1+(\frac{i}{10\sqrt 3})^2}$ and $x=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{1}{10\sqrt 3} \frac{1}{1+(\frac{i}{10\sqrt 3})^2}$. Prove that

1. $x<\frac{\pi}6<y$
2. $\frac{x+y}2<\frac{\pi}6$

**My try**: I have shown that $x,y$ are respectively lower and upper Riemann sum of the function $$I=\sqrt 3 \int_0^1\frac{dx}{3+x^2}=\frac{\pi}6.$$

So we are done with part a). How to deal with part b). Here $$x+y=\frac34\frac{1}{10\sqrt 3}+2\sum_{i=1}^{9}\frac{1}{10\sqrt 3} \frac{1}{1+(\frac{i}{10\sqrt 3})^2}+\frac{1}{10\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{x+y}2$ is the trapezoidal sum.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{3+x^2}.$  Then part (b) actually follows from the fact
$$0 < x < 1 \implies f''(x) = \frac{6(x^2-1)}{(3+x^2)^3} < 0$$

Graphically, this is because $\frac{x+y}{2}$ can be reinterpreted as the "trapezoid rule" for the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.$

Comment: Will you please elaborate a bit? Why does b) follow from $f''(x)<0$?

Comment: I still think the most intuitive way to see this is graphically.  That is, the trapezoidal rule approximates the area  under the graph of $f$ with trapezoids formed by connecting the endpoints on each subinterval.  Since the second derivative is always negative on $0 < x < 1,$ the function $f$ is concave-down and therefore every trapezoid lies strictly under its graph, and the trapezoid rule gives an underestimate for the integral.

Comment: For a rigorous proof, one may refer to the proof of the [error formula for the trapezoid rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis), noting $f$ only shows up as a second derivative.

Comment: If you need me to show why $\frac{x+y}{2}$ can be identified with the trapezoidal rule for the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx,$ I can do that, but any rigorous proof I give would be essentially copying the better part of the wiki (but in our problem, we can reduce to the case of $N=1$)

Comment: Yeah if you can give me a simplified answer, that will be of great help!